# Running command on task startup

Tags: conemu

Im trying to run a command in conemu when I open up a console from a task.
For example, I want to open a bash terminal and run node -v to see my current node version. My Current task commands look like this:

```
set "PATH=%ConEmuBaseDirShort%\wsl;%PATH%" & %ConEmuBaseDirShort%\conemu-cyg-64.exe --wsl -cur_console:pm:/mnt node -v
```

This opens a bash terminal and executes node -v, but then closes the process, giving me the error

```
Root process was alive less than 10 sec, ExitCode=0
```

My expected result is that the output of node -v would be visable, and under that would be a working bash console.

```
v12.6.0
root@COMPUTER:/mnt/c# _
```

I had it like this in my previous environment so I know it's possible, but I don't remember how I did it.

Comment: Actually, it's not clear what behavior do you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You can suppress this error by adding the flag `-new_console:n`.

This is more a feature than an error; if your process runs and ends in less than ten seconds, ConEmu will keep the tab open until you press a key, just so you can see the message it produces.

More info [here](https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/issues/1556)!

Edit: You're also able to change the amount of time before this message shows in the settings, or set it to never/always show

Edit 2: To force a 'Press Enter or Escape to close the console' message, append `-new_console:c`

Comment: I guess I should  have specified, I would like the results of the command to actually stay up, not just bypass the error and close the console.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my question to clarify what I'm looking for.